# Expanding sidebar CSS unexpected behavior in Safari?

Tags: php, html, css, z-index

I've been working on a web app project for school, and I've designed an expanding sidebar with HTML/CSS. The sidebar is supposed to have a z-index greater than everything else on the page. I use Chrome, so I didn't notice until recently that in Safari Version 14.0.3 (on MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3), my sidebar only behaves properly some of the time, sometimes appearing on top of the contents of the page as intended, and other times appearing on top of everything except a table on one of the pages (player-search.php). I was hoping I could get some advice as to how to fix this problem, as I've never seen an issue like this before. Many thanks in advance, and happy to provide additional info.

[Here is a screenshot of the behavior on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPKkK.png)
&
[here is a screenshot of the behavior on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0CTf.png).

It's also hosted on Heroku [here](http:///https://cs4750-fantasy-sports.herokuapp.com/player-search) if you want to interact with it.

Here is the file structure:

```
project/
│    player-search.php
│
│────css/
│      reset.css
│      styles.css
│      sidebar.css
│
└────includes/
       footer.php
       header.php
       sidebar.php
```

Here is the relevant code:

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Fantasy Soccer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<?php function isCurrentPath($path) {...} ?>

<body>

  <div style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: 10vh 90vh; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; color: white;">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <a style="height: 100%; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 25px; color: white;" href="/">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 100%; font-size: 32px;">Upper90</div>
      </a>
      <div style="font-size: 45px; padding: 0 25px;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white; height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center;" href="/"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;">
      <?php include_once "includes/sidebar.php" ?>
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: var(--light-blue); position: absolute; z-index: 5;">
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<?php

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$sidebar_items = array(

  "Home" => array("classes" => "fas fa-home", "path" => "/"),
  "How to Play" => array("classes" => "fas fa-info-circle", "path" => "/how-to-play"),
  "Player Search" => array("classes" => "fas fa-search", "path" => "/player-search"),
  "My Roster" => array("classes" => "fas fa-user-friends", "path" => "/my-roster"),
  "Submit Feedback" => array("classes" => "fas fa-comment", "path" => "/submit-feedback")
);

function getIconClassFromValue($v) {...}

function transformPath($path) {...}

function getHoverClassFromURI($uri) {...}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sidebar.css">

<div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; z-index: 10;">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-contents">
      <?php foreach ($sidebar_items as $key => $value) : ?>
        <a <?php getHoverClassFromURI($value['path']) ?> href=<?php echo transformPath($value['path']); ?>>
          <div>
            <div class="sidebar-icon">
              <div><i <?php getIconClassFromValue($value['classes']) ?>></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-text">
              <div><?php echo $key ?></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**player-search.php**

```
<?php include_once "includes/header.php" ?>

<?php

$rows = array("One" => "One",
              "Two" => "Two",
              "Three" => "Three",
              "Four" => "Four",
              "Five" => "Five",
              "Six" => "Six");

?>

<div class="inner-page-contents">
  <div class="player-search">
    <div class="player-search-top-section">
      <div class="ps-input">
        <input type="text" name="player-search" id="player-search" placeholder="Search Player Info..." autofocus>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="ps-dropdown">
        <label for="actions">Actions: </label>
        <select name="actions" id="actions-input">
          <option selected disabled value="">----- Select Option -----</option>
          <option value="Add">Add Player(s) To Team</option>
          <option value="Remove">Remove Player(s) From Team</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="ps-dropdown">
        <label for="sort">Sort By: </label>
        <select name="sort" id="sort-input">
          <option selected disabled value="">----- Select Option -----</option>
          <option value="Name_A_Z">Name (A-Z)</option>
          <option value="Name_Z_A">Name (Z-A)</option>
          <option value="Goals">Goals</option>
          <option value="Assists">Assists</option>
          <option value="MVPs">MVPs</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="player-search-bottom-section">
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr class="table-header">
              <th>Select</th>
              <th>Player Name</th>
              <th>Goals</th>
              <th>Assists</th>
              <th>MVPs</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $key => $value) : ?>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include_once "includes/footer.php" ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**reset.css**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

**styles.css**

```
:root {
  --dark-blue: #042d4a;
  --blue: #59819e;
  --light-blue: #a1d3f7;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@500&display=swap");

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inner-page-contents {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-search {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 90%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #393e43;
}

.player-search-top-section {
  padding: 0 2.5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.player-search-top-section input {
  height: 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.player-search-top-section select {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ps-input {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}

.ps-input > i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 7px;
}

.ps-dropdown label {
  margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#player-search {
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#player-search:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px purple;
}

.player-search-bottom-section {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.table-wrapper {
  height: 90%;
  width: 95%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

tr:not(.table-header) {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.table-wrapper td {
  border: 2px solid #666666;
}

.table-wrapper tr {
  background: #cccccc;
}

.table-wrapper tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.table-header > th {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
```

**sidebar.css**

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

.sidebar-wrapper:hover .sidebar-contents {
  width: 300px;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

.sidebar-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.sidebar-item.active {
  background: var(--blue);
}

.sidebar-item:hover {
  background: var(--blue);
}

.sidebar-item > div {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  width: 50px;
}

.sidebar-icon > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-text {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: font-size 0.4s, margin-left 0.4s;
}

.sidebar-text > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-wrapper:hover .sidebar-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: font-size 0.4s, margin-left 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
```